# Check if alt-attribute on images has value and add <div> with another image inside

Tags: jquery, image, html, prepend, alt

I am rather new to JQuery & Javascript so I need a little help with a piece of code in JQuery that I am trying to write. What I want to do is to write a function that looks through all images in a certain post in Wordpress and checks to see if they have `alt="watermark"`.

If they do then I want to wrap `<div>` around each `<img>`. In addition I want to place a second image inside that `<div>` on top of the other image. I have managed to create the `div` around the images based on the `alt`. I have also been able to add an image on the existing one inside that `div`. However I am not able to repeat that last action. My code only adds image into the first `<div>`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img[alt*='watermark']").wrap('<div id="watermark" />');  
$('#watermark').prepend("<img src='images/watermark.png'/>");
});
```

Comment: @adeneo Changing the ID to classes made it work! Did not know that. Thank you very much for your help adeneo.

Comment: @KjetilRavnås - You're welcome. ID's should always be unique in the document, so there can only be one element with that unique ID etc. That's why jQuery stops once the first one is found, it does'nt expect there to be more elements with the same ID, as that would be invalid markup.

Comment: Just a heads up - test it in IE. When using "wrap" IE is sometimes testy if you don't have valid html markup. If you find that IE gives issues, add the closing </div> in the .wrap mehod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `before()` to add an image before the current image :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img[alt*='watermark']").wrap('<div id="watermark" />');
                              .before("<img src='images/watermark.png'/>");
});
```

This selector:

```
$('#vannmerke_hvit')
```

indicates an ID, and ID's are unique, so that only works for one element, the first one. You could change it to a class to make it work with multiple elements.

Lykke til!